# PsExec.exe throws error when running Powershell script in SYSTEM context - Error creating key file on {machineName}: Access is denied

Tags: powershell, vpn, psexec, pki

I am trying to run a powershell script in the System context using PsExec, but get the error

```
C:\Users\{myUserName}>PsExec.exe -i -s "C:\windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"

PsExec v2.34 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2021 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

Error creating key file on {MachineName}:
Access is denied.
```

This is simply to open up a PowerShell terminal with the system account. My end game is to use PsExec to create a PBK file like this

```
psexec.exe -i -s powershell.exe .\convertXML.ps1 -xmlFilePath .\vpntemplate.xml -ProfileName "TestVPN"
```

I am using the resources referenced here [Configure VPN device Tunnels in WIndows 10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-access/vpn/vpn-device-tunnel-config#configure-the-vpn-device-tunnel)

Comment: Try `PsExec.exe -i -s "C:\windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -noprofile` (just a wild guess)

Answer (score 1):

@zett42 when I opened a command window as an administrator and tried your command, it worked as I expected.

```
psexec.exe -i -s powershell.exe -noprofile
```

Alternatively, I think it was psexec's EULA that was causing problems because I ran this and it worked flawlessly as well

```
psexec.exe -i -s powershell.exe -nobanner -accepteula
```

Comment: I am encountering the same problem with psexec. I have tried using `-nobanner` as well as running `psexec.exe -i -s powershell.exe -nobanner -accepteula` but all give the same result: "Error creating key file on {MachineName}." (Although my error is *slightly* different - instead of "Access denied," it says, "A device attached to the system is not functioning." No idea what that means though, since I don't have any peripherals attached, and Device Manager doesn't show any misbehaving drivers...)

Answer (score 0):

This can be the cause:
PSEXESVC.exe was blocked by the attack surface reduction (ASR) rule "Block process creations originating from PSExec and WMI commands"